# Merge SwiftyJSON.swiftmodule fails with error No such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I have upgraded to Xcode 7 and my project to Swift2. My project is a hybrid of ObjC and Swift code. I also upgraded to cocoa pods 0.38.2. After the upgrade, the project has failed to compile. Specifically, compilation is failing with the following error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

I have traced this problem to the following message:

```
MergeSwiftModule normal x86_64 /Users/murdockcrc/repos/HdV%20-%20iOS/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyJSON.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftyJSON.swiftmodule
which fails with the following error:
<unknown>:0: error: error opening '/Users/murdockcrc/repos/HdV%20-%20iOS/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyJSON.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftyJSON-Swift.h' for output: No such file or directory
```

The problem is not related to SwiftyJSON only. Even if I remove this library, another of my Swift dependencies will fail with the same error.

I am not knowledgeable in the way cocoa pods works with frameworks and mixed objc-swift projects, but I supposed something is wrong with the umbrella headers and making the dependencies accessible to the swift compiler.

Here is my podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Helden der Volksmusik' do

pod 'DateTools', '1.5.0'
pod 'UALogger', '~> 0.3'
pod 'KZPropertyMapper', '2.5.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.5.4'
pod "MTJSONUtils"
pod "TTTAttributedLabel", "1.13.3"
pod 'PureLayout', '2.0.6'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'xcode7'
pod 'SwiftDate', :git => 'https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
pod 'SwiftSpinner', '0.8.0'

end

target 'Helden der VolksmusikTests' do

pod 'DateTools', '1.5.0'
pod 'UALogger', '~> 0.3'
pod 'KZPropertyMapper', '2.5.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.5.4'
pod "MTJSONUtils"
pod "TTTAttributedLabel", "1.13.3"
pod 'PureLayout', '2.0.6'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'xcode7'
pod 'SwiftDate', :git => 'https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'

end
```